# Zero curl and zero divergence does not imply zero field!

Tags: electromagnetism

Reading through the solution to some physics problem, the author claims to show that the magnetic field is some region of space is 0 everywhere because it has 0 curl, and since the B field always has zero divergence, it is thus the zero field.

This doesn't make sense, they're are examples of nonzero vector fields with both zero curl and zero divergence, for example a constant field (and probably other examples).

Comment: The intended meaning of the work 'everywhere' may be important here.

Comment: http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_18.html Feynman tries to show that the B field of a spherically symmetric distribution is zero. He shows the curl is 0, fine. Then he just asserts "There is no magnetic field in our example"

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou If the curl of the magnetic field is zero, then B obeys Laplace's equation.  The uniqueness property of Laplace's equation means that if you can find a function which obeys some set of boundary conditions, then it's the *only* function which obeys that set of boundary conditions.

Comment: @JoshuaBenabou Any field generated by a finite, localized source goes to zero at infinity - the boundary condition is therefore B(infinity)=0.  The function B = 0 everywhere satisfies this boundary condition, so it is the only one which works.

Comment: @J.Murray That should be an answer!